# Why is app crashing in iPhone simulator; how can I fix this?

Tags: xcode, ios, crash, ios-simulator, viewdidload

I'm working on an app that uses a navigation controller. When I build, I get no errors or warnings. I've defined a method `myMethod` in `FirstViewController.m` file, then in `viewDidLoad` I call the method with `[self myMethod];`.

When I built and ran from the Console, I got nothing. So I put `NSLog()` statements like so:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
NSLog(@"Entering viewDidLoad");
[self myMethod];
NSLog(@"Called myMethod");
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The Console never returns the second NSLog statement, leading me to believe that the app crashes while calling the method.

I've tried this with the simulator set to iOS 4.0.1 as well as iOS 4.1. I'm building against the iOS 4.1 SDK. I really appreciate any help you can offer.

**Update:** I ran the Debugger, which seems to show the problem being in `myMethod`. I only make it through a few lines of code in that method before I receive "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". The lines of code are:

```
-(void)myMethod {
NSMutableArray *someStuff;
NSMutableArray *someMoreStuff;

stuffSections=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Some Stuff",@"Some More Stuff",nil];

someStuff=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
someMoreStuff=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[someStuff addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Item Name",@"name",@"Item Picture.png",@"picture",@"http://theurl.net/",@"url",@"1",@"itemCode",nil]];
```

But it appears that I can't get past this first attempt to add something to the `someStuff` array.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and use the debugger. And actually run with the debugger attached (not just debug target).

Comment: Okay, I placed the breakpoint immediately after [self myMethod]. In the Debugger Console it says "Program received signal: 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'." I'm new to this, though, and have no idea what these results in the Debugger window mean ...

Comment: Try running with command+Y instead of command+R. That'll launch with the debugger attached. When your program crashes, execution will pause at the offending line giving you a chance to find out where it is and to inspect the values of your variables at that moment.

Comment: Well, I've been doing that, but I'm not really pulling anything out of the information provided (seems to be the challenging part of teaching myself). All I know is that the failure comes while trying to add the first NSMutableDictionary to the NSMutableArray someStuff.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a problem in "myMethod".  If I had to guess, I would say you are trying to reference an object that was auto-released and not retained.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the alloc when initializing someStuff and someMoreStuff. It should be

```
   someStuff = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   someMoreStuff = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: I did have it in the code, but failed to type it here. I think I'll start copy-pasting. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you cross checked the two MutableArrays? Do they have been allocated successfully? You get "**EXC_BAD_ACCESS**" when the app got into a corrupted state that is usually due to a **memory management** issue. I guess the arrays are not allocated.

Try allocating this way.

```
NSMutableArray * someStuff = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];
NSMutableArray * someMoreStuff = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];
```

add a breakpoint there are check in the debug area and confirm whether they are being allocated successfully. If there is a memory to each of these array, then they are allocated.